# Android: LruCache does not work

Tags: android

I followed the link on developer.android.com and created the following code:

```
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()) / 1024;
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory;

    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
            return super.sizeOf(key, value);
        }
    };

    if(getBitmapFromCache(sBitmapCacheKey) == null) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "No image cached");
        applyBlur();
    }else{
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Found image cached, applying");
        setBackgroundFromCache();
    }
```

method applyBlur()

```
    private void applyBlur() {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "applying blur");
    blur(convert(WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).getDrawable()), null);
}

private void blur(Bitmap bitmap, View view) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float radius = 25;

    ...          

    addBitmapToCache(sBitmapCacheKey, overlay);

    rs.destroy();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "It took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
}
```

Where `applyBlur()` is a method I use to create the `Bitamp` and add to `LruCache`.

From the Logcat it always says "No image cached" and will create a whole new `Bitmap`

I am quite a newbie so I haven't used cache before, any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are you synchronizing the cache?  Where do you set the cache limit? can you show your appyBlur() method

Comment: Okay, my bad, I added the cache size in the edit

Comment: *return super.sizeOf(key, value);*

Comment: updated applyBlur() method as well

Comment: You realize the Cache is going to be empty the first time you try to get each Bitmap, and so for each image it's going to print "No image cached", right?

Comment: I didn't realize. How should I fix it?

Comment: There's nothing to fix. The cache starts empty. You put bitmaps into it that you're going to use frequently, and it stores them in memory until you need them. When you need them, you ask the cache for them, and if it has them it returns them, otherwise you load them from wherever (drawables in your case it looks like). The first time it's never going to have it, but it should the second time. You don't appear to be loading your images a second time from the code I can see here, however, so I'm not even sure why you're using the cache.

Comment: @Carl Anderson I try to retrieve the bitmap with setBackgroundFromCache() and because processing the image takes time which affects the user experience in my case so I don't want to have to process the image every single time so I'm using cache. If you have any ideas how I can achieve something like I've mentioned, I'd be more than grateful to hear about them. Thanks

Comment: Where are you initializing your Cache, and what class owns it? Your question doesn't have enough information to answer.
Also, @blackbelt already pointed out that your `sizeOf` function isn't returning a good value, you should be manually returning the size of the Bitmap instead of calling `super`.

Comment: Yes. You're initializing your Cache in terms of bytes, not in terms of the number of images you want to store. You either need to initialize it to store, say, 10 images (instead of using the memory calculation you're doing now), or you need to correctly evaluate how many of those bytes your images are using.

Comment: @Carl Anderson sorry for the late reply. I initiallized the cache in onCreate of the activity. And do I I pass an argument like bitmap.getByteCount()?

Answer (score 2):

Your cache isn't working is for a couple of reasons. As discussed already, you need to have matching size functions, first of all. You can't initialize the cache to a memory size and then use image count in the `sizeOf` function (or vice versa). If you want to use image size, you need to change your `sizeOf` function to something like this:

```
@Override
protected int sizeOf(final String key, final Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();
}
```

Secondly, you need to have a better grasp of how the cache is used, and how the `Activity` lifecycle works. Creating and storing this in an Activity isn't going to work, because an Activity can potentially be destroyed by the Android operating system at any moment, which will cause your Cache to be garbage-collected (removed from memory).
One way to avoid this is to create a new class that extends `LruCache`, and then have a singleton getter function that initializes the cache, and is available for anyone to use. Here's an example:

```
public final class Example extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> {

    private static Example instance;

    private Example(final int maxSize) {
        super(maxSize);
    }

    public static Example get() {
        if (instance == null) {
            final int cacheSize = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()) / 1024;
            instance = new Example(cacheSize);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(final String key, final Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();
    }

}
```

In order to use this in your `Activity`, you simply call `Example.get()`, and that will consistently give you the same cache every time, across all of your activities, ensuring that if you store a Bitmap in one Activity, that it's available for any other Activity too.